# How do I reduce redundancy in state logic for repeated processes (handshakes)?

Tags: vhdl

I'm working with an IP that uses the AXI Lite protocol. The read/write handshakes take up a few states in my state diagram. The problem is that I have to create the same set of state for each handshake in the state diagram, which is really redundant. Is there a way I can reduce redundancy?

I have tried writing the handshakes into a function. However, because I'm setting and reading signals from within the function, the code will not synthesize. I've considered turning the handshakes into separate processes and using a flag to denote whether they are busy or not.

Sample Read Handshake:

```vhdl
case state is
    when 0 =>
        if arready = '0' then
            arvalid <= '1';
            rready <= '1';
            araddr <= SOME_ADDRESS
        else
            arvalid <= '0';
            state := 1;
    when 1 =>
        if rvalid = '1' then
            SOME_SIGNAL_STD_LOGIC_VECTOR <= rdata;
            rready <= '0';
            state := THE_NEXT_STATE;
```

Comment: If you have the same sequence of states appearing more than once in a state diagram, how about splitting your state machine into two? The repeated sequence of states is basically the slave state machine, which is kicked off by the master state machine whenever it wants to follow that sequence of states. (And the master state machine would probably not change state until the slave had done its thing.)

Comment: Treat the Addr channel and data channels independently, dont combine them in a single state machine.

Comment: Another option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612604/substatemachine/32620346#32620346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a master-slave FSM as suggested by Matthew Taylor in the comments: [How do I reduce redundancy in state logic for repeated processes (handshakes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511674/how-do-i-reduce-redundancy-in-state-logic-for-repeated-processes-handshakes?noredirect=1#comment101491700_57511674).

The redundant code was stored in a separate 'slave' process. The redundant code runs only when the 'master' kickstarts the slave process (ie asserting a slave_start signal low -> high).

Here's a generic overview I came up with to facilitate the master-slave configuration:

1. The master FSM sets any appropriate signals used in the slave process, asserts a slave_start signal high, and waits for the slave process.
2. The slave reads the slave_start as high and begins to process data.
3. The slave asserts a slave_done signal high.
4. The master reads the slave_done as high and asserts slave_start low. The master moves on to the next state in the FSM.
5. The slave asserts slave_done low to get ready for next 'kickstart.'

Comment: Thanks for getting back with your eventual solution